# self-describing project in Eclipse using m2e

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

I'm using Eclipse and m2e to import a Maven project into Eclipse.

The eclipse documentation states the following about the .project file:

```
The purpose of this file is to make the project self-describing, 
so that a project that is zipped up or released to a server can be 
correctly recreated in another workspace.
```

However, the .project file does not contain no information about the imported Java files nor the pom.xml. It only contains some build commands and natures. Thus, I don't understand how it makes the project self-describing.

It seems that each developer that downloads repository for the first time will need to import the Maven project inside Eclipse again. I'd like to have a meta file that contained at least the pom.xml path so that developers could have a ready environment after downloading the repository content and didn't need to import the Maven project into Eclipse. Is that possible?

Comment: Please explain _"developers could have a ready environment after downloading the repository content and didn't need to import the Maven project into Eclipse."_ What do you mean by a ready environment?  What do you expect your developers to do without importing the projec into IDE?

Comment: I want the developer to just open a project file and have all source files loaded in its project workspace. This is the usual process using other IDEs such as Visual Studio, Code Warrior and CodeBlocks.

Comment: This is the whole point of m2e, the .classpath and .project is auto generated when create/import project in Eclipse. As long as your project is properly structured and mavenized, You don't need them to describe the project, as the pom really describe all and better (more readable, configurable and maintainable). See [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Object_Model#Project_Object_Model) for a better explanation.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean : a long time ago (_in a galaxy far far away..._), when we used JBuilder, we used to double click a file with an extension **.jpx**, and JBuilder was launched with this project opened. Unfortunately, I don't think Eclipse works this way. You rather have to _import_ everything from Eclipse. For example : _Import > Existing Projects into Workspace_

Comment: Maven gives the ability to unbind your project to a specific IDE, it provides a more open development environment compare to a paid IDE-dependent descriptor like .jpx or .sln.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, now I understand. Eclipse works differently from other IDEs in the project importing aspect. Eclipse documentation should be updated to reflect this better, the above description of a .project file is confusing for a developer used to other IDEs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically speaking, Eclipse doesn't know anything about maven.  The .project file is Eclipse's way of storing metadata about the project in a file that's contained within the project (although nowadays some of that metadata has moved to the manifest.MF file).  The .project file still contains information about natures (which are used by tools to identify which projects are of interest to the tools) and builders (which describe what tools to invoke as resources in the project are changed).  In this way the .project makes the project self describing.

Maven is a relative newcomer (albeit a stable and well-established one) to the Eclipse world.  As you point out maven stores all of its project info in a pom.xml file.  Maven fits itself into the Eclipse world by providing two actions, "Update Project Configuration" and "Update Project Dependencies", that take the information in the pom.xml file and update the contents of the .project and .classpath files.

So instead of manually editing the .project and .classpath files as you suggest, a developer only has to invoke those two functions after extracting an Eclipse project from a repository.

Comment: What about the 1st time the developer downloads the repository? He'll need to import the Maven project (pom.xml) into Eclipse, as no information about pom.xml file is stored in Eclipse files afaik ? Or is it stored somewhere and just opening the Eclipse .project file will open my Maven project in Eclipse?

Comment: The pom file should be versioned along with all the other source files in the project.  You'll have to run the "import maven project" to get maven to recognize that it needs to work against the new project, too.